# Word for a guest insulting the host

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Very often in movies there are guests that insult their host or cause grief to their host on purpose or by just being clumsy for whatever reason, is there a word for such people? in either good or bad context?

Further explanation : Type of people that are good by their actions and deeds, but verbally they are abusive and unpleasant? They have a contradicting duality of not showing respect, yet they behave with best interest of the host.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4842/2085).

Comment: If you're talking to fellow film buffs, you might refer to this type of guest as "[a Boudu](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0022718/)."

Answer (score -1):

Sociopath.  That word may be a little extreme thou.

Comment: Impolite is a bit milder.  I would have nuked it but once you post .... that's seems to be it.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that although verbally they are insulting the guest their actions are exactly opposite. They will help and will have the good intentions towards their host, yet they cant help themselves with what they say.